# How to recover midway through a method, when Android app backgrounds

Tags: android, android-activity, xamarin.android, android-lifecycle, xamarin.essentials

I have a Xamarin Android App that during a particular method, launches third-party code (Xamarin Essentials Lib) and ultimately the camera.

I understand that during the lifecycle of the app, an activity may be put into the background, and essentially be 'put to sleep'.  I have code during a normal activity restore, that will recover the data etc.

However, when trying to use Xamarin Essentials Lib to launch the camera and return a photo (instead of doing this manually), the following entry point back to the activity is not used:

```
OnActivityResult(){}
```

Instead the method just awaits the response of obtaining the photo, during the normal execution of the calling method:

```
private async void TakePhoto()
    {
        // Photo requested

        var photo = await MediaPicker.CapturePhotoAsync();

       // Photo taken

    }
```

If when calling TakePhoto(), the Android device does not fully background the app (in the lifecycle sense), the method successfully hits "Photo taken".  If the app is fully backgrounded (as soon as the camera app loads in front it decides to free up resources), once the photo is taken, the activity restores itself, but the original method is no longer executing, so I am unable to continue to get the photo response, thus "Photo taken" is never hit.

So my question is, how am I implementing this wrong, given how the Android activity lifecycle works?

Comment: `once the photo is taken, the activity restores itself, but the original method is no longer executing, so I am unable to continue to get the photo response, thus "Photo taken" is never hit.` can not understand what you mean? Do you want to use `MediaPicker.CapturePhotoAsync()` to lunch camera?

Comment: Yes I would like to use MediaPicker.CapturePhotoAsync() to lunch camera, but it has to work with the fact that my app will be put into the background, and need to handle being resumed in line with Android activity lifecycle.

Comment: From [using Media Picker](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/media-picker?tabs=android#using-media-picker), all methods must be called on the UI thread because permission checks and requests are automatically handled by Xamarin.Essentials.

Comment: I am doing that.  As I have said, if the app resources do not get recycled by the lifecycle, my code works fine.

Comment: sorry, I don't know how do you call TakePhoto method, when your app is background. I try to reproduce your problem.

Comment: I call the method when it is running.  Do you understand that the camera causes my app to then go in background, which then causes the issue?  At TakePhoto() it is "Running". Once the camera is then launched, photo taken by user, and everything returns to my app, my app is "backgrounded". Thus in this scenario TakePhoto() is no longer running, as the activity now goes straight to OnCreate() and OnResume() to restore.

Comment: I test Media picker using `var result = await Xamarin.Essentials.MediaPicker.CapturePhotoAsync();    if (result != null)
        { var stream = await result.OpenReadAsync();   CamImage = ImageSource.FromStream(() => stream);  }` , and I can get imagesource by result , display in Image control, have no problem.

Comment: Just because your device didn't 'background' (in the lifecycle sense) your test app, as soon as camera launched, doesn't mean other devices won't in that situation.  I need help to handle what I am suppose to do, if it does 'background'.  Maybe you could try and force your test app to 'background' once the camera launches? e.g run CapturePhotoAsync() then goto homescreen launching as many large apps as possible, before returning to camera. It's important that you are only half way through CapturePhotoAsync(), and have launched the camera, but not taken the photo, before stressing the device.

Comment: `Maybe you could try and force your test app to 'background' once the camera launches` if I launch camera, the camera will cover my test app UI. If I force test app background, the camera will background too.

Comment: I don't think you understand.  I don't mean the app is hidden in the background, i mean the activity state is 'background'.  They are not the same thing.

Comment: Just to be clear: "If I force test app background, the camera will background too", at that point, are you able to start a load of different resource hungry apps?  Once you have maxed the resources on the device, if you reveal your app (the camera), are you able to continue to take photo, and resume loading it?  To reiterate, you have to max out the resources, before resuming, otherwise you cannot reproduce.

Comment: yes, I can not reproduce your problem, maybe you can give one gif to describe your problem, or post your problem at github.